# Unable to access jar file while creating war file

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I have put my project files in C/users/usrname/documents/sample/

I went to the directory and tried using

```
java -jar -cvf myapp.war *
```

I have given cmd admin access.
But it gives an error saying "unable to access jar file myapp.war"

Comment: maybe java -jar myapp.war

Comment: I want to create a war file

Answer (score 2):

Try `jar -cvf myapp.war *` going in the project directory.

Comment: im not sure why this is happening

Comment: This command worked perfectly worked for me, try finding why your `jar` command is not working. Make it work and above solution should do the job. Also check for `jar.exe` in `java/jdk/bin`. It should be there

Comment: also make sure your `JAVA_HOME` points to `java/jdk/bin` and not to `java/jdk`